# spring 4 and quartz 1.x

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I have upgraded my project from Spring 2 to Spring 4. I have quartz 1.7 in my project. After I upgraded to Spring 4, I got this error

Invocation  of init method failed; nested exception is 
org.quartz.JobPersistenceException; Couldn't receive trigger: Invalid column name 'SCHED_NAME'

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you updated your quartz version as well?

Comment: I had added and removed the 2.2 jar. Looks like a workspace issue. The error has disappeared after I cleaned the workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at Quartz 2 migration guide

http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/migration-guide

***SHED_NAME*** column was added to all tables in Quartz.

Check your dependencies for Quartz, I think you are on 2.x.x version now.

Comment: thanks for sharing that link. Spring 4 seems to be not compatible with Quartz version 1.x. I have seen dependencies like CronTriggerImpl which are available in Quartz 2.x versions but not in 1.x. I have finally decided to go with 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

Copying the latest quartz.jar in /jboss/server//lib worked for me